# How to detect what device the user is using?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I know there was a thread about this already, but I'm asking this because it isn't working for me.

I put this code outside of my class, and it has no closures around it.

```
public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":           return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
    default:                                        return identifier
    }
 }
}
```

So, up in my didMoveToView, I ran this code:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone4,1" {
        print("yes")
    repeatObstaclesOnPhone()

    }
```

I ran the app then on the iPhone 4S simulator and nothing happened. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your code? – I am pretty sure that when running on the Simulator, modelName returns "Simulator" and not "iPhone4,1".

Comment: How can I debug it? Sorry I'm a beginner and this is my first app!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/

Comment: Wait- I just changed it to "iPhone8,2" and tested it on my personal iPhone 6s Plus, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Don't delete posts after getting an answer. Accept the answer and leave it there for other people.

Comment: I'm sorry :( Can I get it back?

Comment: Yes, go back to the question and hit "undelete".